# Is there any way to use a Wheel date picker in Safari on iOS 14?

Tags: html, ios, web, mobile

In iOS 14, the default datepicker on mobile web is now a modal instead of the wheel design (see the image below).

It seems that in Native apps, you [can still get the Wheel design by setting some parameters](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/controls/pickers/#date-picker). [Parameter docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidatepickerstyle/wheels).

Is there any way on mobile web to use the wheel style? Right now my code looks like:

```html
<input type="date" >
```

Is there any property, CSS style, anything... that I could use to get Safari/iOS to render the datepicker in `wheels` style?

[image]

[Image Source](https://blog.mobiscroll.com/date-time-dial-scroller-keypad/)

Comment: did you ever find a solution? When did Safari change to this new design.

Comment: Nope, haven't found a way. I think they changed the design as part of iOS 14.